# I am trying to find the time complexity for this 2 methods

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

```
def mysort1(x):
    y = list(x)
    y.sort() 
    z = [0]*len(y)
    for i in range(0, len(y)):
        z[i] = y[i]
    return z

def mysort2(x):
    y = list(x)
    y.sort()
    z = []
    for i in range(0, len(y)):
        z.insert(0,y[len(y)-i-1])
    return z
```

I think both of them have a linear time complexity, considering the loop runs n times in both the methods. What do you think is the time complexity of the code blocks given below.

Comment: If you're going to include the `.sort()` function as part of your complexity and not just the for loops, then it'll be O(n lg n)

Comment: `y.sort()` in both of them should be `O(n log(n))`.  Also in the second one the `z.insert` is a `O(n)` operation making the second one `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Separately your indentation was a syntax error.  I edited it to be indented it as I believe should be intended.

Comment: @btilly n^2 because the insert statement has two operations ? or are you coupling it with the for loop ? Can you please break down your thought process ?

Comment: @Dogdigger Because when you insert at the beginning of the array, Python has to move over everything in the array to make space.  The move is efficiently implemented, but is a `O(n)` operation.  Do `n` of those and you get `O(n^2)`.  Try it with an array with a million elements to see the difference.

Comment: By contrast Python leaves extra space at the end in advance, so assigning to the end is usually `O(1)`.  And the occasional expensive "the whole array needed to find more space" is so rare that its *amortized* expense is still `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, time complexity of your algorithm is O(nlog(n)) because time complexity of array sorting is O(nlog(n)).